# Why is this out of bounds? python

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Enter expression:car.a + var.a
car   Variable
.   Variable
a   Variable
+   operator
var   Variable
.   Variable
a   Variable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Documents\Python\Lexical analyzer.py", line 62, in <module>
    if(check_main(temp[i]) == 'Variable'):
IndexError: list index out of range

for i in range(1,len(temp),2):
if temp[i] == '.':
    if check_main(temp[i-1])=='Variable':
        temp[i-1:i+2]= [''.join(temp[i-1:i+2])]
```

The list was correct ['car.a', '+', 'var.a'] but i don't know why it showed an out of bounds,sorry for my bad english

Comment: You didn't show us the code causing the error, not the code around  line 62 at least

Comment: The line that errored is `if(check_main(temp[i]) == 'Variable'):`, but that's not in the code you've shown us

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's out of bonds because you're modifying the list while iterating over its length. The problem is with this line:

```
temp[i-1:i+2]= [''.join(temp[i-1:i+2])]
```

Here, you changed what once was three items to only one item. So as you iterate over it, the length of your list actually shortens! Quite strange, huh? At one point, `temp[i]` will be no longer valid, since `i` is already bigger than the current `len(temp)`.

You're encountering something like this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[1:4] = [1]
>>> l
[1, 1, 5]
```

Solution? Instead of modifying the list, i'd recommend you to make a new one. Maybe something like this:

```
if check_main(temp[i-1])=='Variable':
    new_list.append(''.join(temp[i-1:i+2]))
```

Hope this helps!